# Set persistent permissions for /var/log/boot.log

Tags: linux, centos, logs

Every time I reboot my CentOS 6.5 computer, it writes the boot log to `/var/log/boot.log`. The permissions on this file are always `644` after a reboot. I want the permissions to be `600`. When I change the file permissions manually using `chmod 600 /var/log/boot.log` it reverts to `644` after the reboot. How can I make this change permanent?

I would prefer the permissions are set when the file is created, instead of having the permissions applied sometime after the boot process is complete (or nearly complete).

Comment: The permissions on these files are governed by Systemd/Upstart. You'll likely have to change the permissions there to get what you want.

Comment: @slm Which configuration files should I look for?